# Entity Framework 7 (Core): DataReader must be closed exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF7 (EF Core).
When I'm trying to update DB items like this in single method...

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    var deadSources =
        await
            db.Source.Where(x => !x.Item.Any())
                .ToListAsync();
    foreach (var srs in deadSources)
    {
        srs.InspectionFailed = true;
        srs.InspectionFailedDescription = "ERROR";
    }
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    var aliveSources =
        await
            db.Source.Where(x => x.Item.Any())
                .ToListAsync();
    foreach (var srs in aliveSources)
    {
        srs.InspectionFailed = false;
        srs.InspectionFailedDescription = string.Empty;
    }
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // Exception here
}
```

... this exception is thrown:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

How can I avoid this? There are two different contexts for each DB request so I can't get why this happens.

Comment: This code was into single using statement, exception was thrown. Thats why I've separated it. But no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not matters if you have one, two or more instance of the same DbContext, the limitation of one datareader per connection exists in database service side, so  you need to enable MultipleActiveResultSets option in your connection string:

```
<add name="XYZ" connectionString="Server=SERVER;Database=DATABASE;
 Trusted_Connection=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I always thought it was one per _connection_. It looks like efcore is not closing the reader or releasing the connection to the pool.

Comment: @JorgeAlves, even is you use ADO.NET directly you will get the same behavior, you need to enable MultipleActiveResultSets if you want to use more than one datareader for the same connection.

Comment: No. Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example that requires MARS. See the reentrant DataReaders? That's basically what MARS allows you to do.
If efcore is doing that in SaveChangesAsync you can bet there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: I don't see conflict in the link and what I state here. EF is not to blame, behind the scenes it open multiple datareader for the same connection, and probably in parallel.

Comment: You had said that it was one reader per _application_. That is wrong.

Anyway, MARS is not required by efcore, so it was definitively a bug.

Comment: Well that was a typo, I meant per connection. This never was a bug of EF Core, if you need MARS or not it depends on how you use EF. In previous versions of EF for example, you need to enable MARS if you use lazy load.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that this may be a bug in the version you're using.

Without MultipleActiveResultSets active you can only have one DataReader *per connection* and nowhere in the code I can see more than one being used. It's very likely efcore is not closing it properly in ToListAsync() and enabling MARS is just masking the problem.

RTM has been released since your question was posted and your particular problem may very well be fixed already.